# How to check that this map is a Group Representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading "Representation Theory of Finite Groups: An Introductory Approach" by Benjamin Steinberg and in Chapter 3, Example 3.1.14 the author gives the following example of a representation:

> Let $\rho \colon S_3 \rightarrow GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be specified on the generators $(12)$ and $(123)$ by $\rho_{(12)}= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \rho_{(123)}= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

The author then suggests that the reader checks this is a representation but I am unsure how to do this. I checked that $\rho_{(12)}^2 = I_2$ and $\rho_{(123)}^3=I_2$ but I'm not sure what else I need to check.

Comment: Do you know about presentations of groups? (Not the same thing as representations!)

Comment: No I don't, but If it helps to solve this problem then I can look it up.

Comment: You need to make sure $\rho$ respects the relations in $S_3$.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to go into more detail regarding how I can check that $\rho$ respects all relations in $S_3$?

Answer (score 2):

What @diracdeltafunk and @Randall are getting at is you first want to write down a presentation for $S_3$ with $(12)$ and $(123)$ as generators. You should check this, but I believe $\langle s,t \; | \; s^2 = 1, t^3 = 1, tst^{-2}s = 1\rangle$ is such a presentation. To verify this you should show that the map $f$ defined on generators by $f(s) = (12)$ and $f(t) = (123)$ is a group isomorphism.

You must then check that $\rho_{(12)}$ and $\rho_{(123)}$ satisfy these relations. So you have checked the first two relations, but the matrices also must satisfy the third relation.